# Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin not starting, Timeout after 90000 milliseconds, adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator-plugin

I am trying to run android tests on my Jenkins server. 
The fist problem is that my machine does not support hardware acceleration. I can see this in the logs so it could be the problem:

```
15:56:33 emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm
15:56:33 emulator: WARNING: x86_64 emulation may not work without hardware acceleration!
```

I can start the emulator by passing the following flags:

```
-accel off  -no-accel   -no-audio -gpu off -verbose
```

But it seems to wait for the emulator and times out. 
Please see the full logs from the Jenkins server:

```
15:55:34 Started by user Paul Stafford
15:55:34 Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidJenkins
15:55:34  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
15:55:34 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
15:55:34  > git config remote.origin.url https://www.boomtastic.org/boomtastic/mobile-android-boom.git # timeout=10
15:55:34 Fetching upstream changes from https://www.boomtastic.org/boomtastic/mobile-android-boom.git
15:55:34  > git --version # timeout=10
15:55:34 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
15:55:34  > git fetch --tags --progress https://www.boomtastic.org/boomtastic/mobile-android-boom.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
15:55:37  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/feature-bees/new_android_app^{commit} # timeout=10
15:55:37  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/feature-bees/new_android_app^{commit} # timeout=10
15:55:37 Checking out Revision b3f9bf59d5a55b33a4eb12914ff4a6c3eb5ea7f6 (refs/remotes/origin/feature-bees/new_android_app)
15:55:37  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
15:55:37  > git checkout -f b3f9bf59d5a55b33a4eb12914ff4a6c3eb5ea7f6
15:55:37  > git rev-list b3f9bf59d5a55b33a4eb12914ff4a6c3eb5ea7f6 # timeout=10
15:55:37 [android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5
15:55:37 [android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd
15:55:37 [android] /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/android create avd -f -a -c 32M -s WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins -t android-23 --abi x86_64
15:55:50 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb start-server
15:55:53 * daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5825 *
15:55:53 * daemon started successfully *
15:55:53 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb start-server
15:55:53 [android] Starting Android emulator
15:55:53 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5758,5759 -report-console tcp:5863,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-window -accel off -no-accel -no-audio -gpu off -verbose
15:55:53 WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
15:55:54 emulator: Android virtual device file at: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.ini
15:55:54 emulator: virtual device content at /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd
15:55:54 emulator: virtual device config file: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/config.ini
15:55:54 emulator: using core hw config path: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
15:55:54 emulator: Found AVD target API level: 23
15:55:54 emulator: Read property file at /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//build.prop
15:55:54 emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
15:55:54 emulator: found skin 'WVGA800' in directory: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platforms/android-23/skins/
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -skin WVGA800
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platforms/android-23/skins/
15:55:54 emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platforms/android-23/skins//WVGA800/hardware.ini
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//kernel-qemu
15:55:54 emulator: Target arch = 'x86_64'
15:55:54 emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
15:55:54 emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//ramdisk.img
15:55:54 emulator: Using initial system image: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//system.img
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/userdata.img
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -cache /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/cache.img
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/sdcard.img
15:55:54 emulator: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
15:55:54 emulator: VM heap size 48MB is below hardware specified minimum of 192MB,setting it to that value
15:55:54 emulator: System image is read only
15:55:54 emulator: autoconfig: -snapstorage /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/snapshots.img
15:55:54 emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
15:55:54 emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 10.1.10.3 10.1.10.5
15:55:54 emulator: trying to load skin file '/opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platforms/android-23/skins//WVGA800/layout'
15:55:54 emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 10.1.10.3 10.1.10.5
15:55:54 emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
15:55:54 Content of hardware configuration file:
15:55:54   hw.cpu.arch = x86_64
15:55:54   hw.cpu.ncore = 2
15:55:54   hw.ramSize = 1024
15:55:54   hw.screen = multi-touch
15:55:54   hw.mainKeys = true
15:55:54   hw.trackBall = true
15:55:54   hw.keyboard = false
15:55:54   hw.keyboard.lid = false
15:55:54   hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
15:55:54   hw.dPad = true
15:55:54   hw.gsmModem = true
15:55:54   hw.gps = true
15:55:54   hw.battery = true
15:55:54   hw.accelerometer = true
15:55:54   hw.audioInput = true
15:55:54   hw.audioOutput = true
15:55:54   hw.sdCard = true
15:55:54   hw.sdCard.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/sdcard.img
15:55:54   disk.cachePartition = true
15:55:54   disk.cachePartition.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/cache.img
15:55:54   disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
15:55:54   hw.lcd.width = 480
15:55:54   hw.lcd.height = 800
15:55:54   hw.lcd.depth = 16
15:55:54   hw.lcd.density = 160
15:55:54   hw.lcd.backlight = true
15:55:54   hw.gpu.enabled = false
15:55:54   hw.gpu.mode = off
15:55:54   hw.gpu.blacklisted = no
15:55:54   hw.initialOrientation = portrait
15:55:54   hw.camera.back = emulated
15:55:54   hw.camera.front = none
15:55:54   vm.heapSize = 192
15:55:54   hw.sensors.light = true
15:55:54   hw.sensors.pressure = true
15:55:54   hw.sensors.humidity = true
15:55:54   hw.sensors.proximity = true
15:55:54   hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
15:55:54   hw.sensors.orientation = true
15:55:54   hw.sensors.temperature = true
15:55:54   hw.useext4 = true
15:55:54   kernel.path = /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//kernel-qemu
15:55:54   kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
15:55:54   kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
15:55:54   disk.ramdisk.path = /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//ramdisk.img
15:56:33   disk.systemPartition.initPath = /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//system.img
15:56:33   disk.systemPartition.size = 1280m
15:56:33   disk.dataPartition.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/userdata-qemu.img
15:56:33   disk.dataPartition.initPath = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/userdata.img
15:56:33   disk.dataPartition.size = 2g
15:56:33   disk.snapStorage.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/snapshots.img
15:56:33   avd.name = hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins
15:56:33 .
15:56:33 emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
15:56:33 emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm
15:56:33 emulator: WARNING: x86_64 emulation may not work without hardware acceleration!
15:56:33 QEMU options list:
15:56:33 emulator: argv[00] = "/opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/emulator64-x86"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[01] = "-audio"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[02] = "none"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[03] = "-dns-server"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[04] = "10.1.10.3,10.1.10.5"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[05] = "-serial"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[06] = "null"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[07] = "-serial"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[08] = "null"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[09] = "-boot-property"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[10] = "persist.sys.language=en"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[11] = "-boot-property"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[12] = "persist.sys.country=US"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[13] = "-android-ports"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[14] = "5758,5759"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[15] = "-android-report-console"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[16] = "tcp:5863,max=60"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[17] = "-disable-kvm"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[18] = "-android-hw"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[19] = "/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[20] = "-append"
15:56:33 emulator: argv[21] = "qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=0 ndns=2"
15:56:33 Concatenated QEMU options:
15:56:33  /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/emulator64-x86 -audio none -dns-server 10.1.10.3,10.1.10.5 -serial null -serial null -boot-property persist.sys.language=en -boot-property persist.sys.country=US -android-ports 5758,5759 -android-report-console tcp:5863,max=60 -disable-kvm -android-hw /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/hardware-qemu.ini -append 'qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=0 ndns=2'
15:56:33 emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
15:56:33 emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
15:56:33 emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyGF
15:56:33 emulator: AVD Name: hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins
15:56:33 emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
15:56:33 emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
15:56:33 emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
15:56:33 emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
15:56:33 emulator: system partition format: ext4
15:56:33 emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x50000000,file=/opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0,readonly
15:56:33 emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
15:56:33 emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x80000000,file=/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
15:56:33 emulator: cache partition format: ext4
15:56:33 emulator: Creating empty cache partition image at: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/cache.img
15:56:33 Creating filesystem with parameters:
15:56:33     Size: 69206016
15:56:33     Block size: 4096
15:56:33     Blocks per group: 32768
15:56:33     Inodes per group: 4224
15:56:33     Inode size: 256
15:56:33     Journal blocks: 1024
15:56:33     Label: 
15:56:33     Blocks: 16896
15:56:33     Block groups: 1
15:56:33     Reserved block group size: 7
15:56:33 Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
15:56:33 emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_-jenkins.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
15:56:33 emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '192m'
15:56:33 emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
15:56:33 emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
15:56:33 emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
15:56:33 emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 10.1.10.3 10.1.10.5
15:56:33 emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=0 ndns=2
15:56:33 emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/bios.bin
15:56:33 
15:56:33 emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin
15:56:33 
15:56:33 emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin
15:56:33 
15:56:33 emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin
15:56:33 
15:56:34 emulator: Adding boot property: 'persist.sys.language' = 'en'
15:56:34 emulator: Adding boot property: 'persist.sys.country' = 'US'
15:56:34 emulator: (android_emulation_setup) using custom adb server port 5825
15:56:34 emulator: ro.adb.qemud invalid or not found, API >= 16, defaulting ro.adb.qemud = 0
15:56:34 emulator: (setup_console_and_adb_ports) trying console port 5758, adb port 5759 (legacy: true)
15:56:34 emulator: (android_console_start) initializing on port 5758
15:56:34 emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5759' to ADB server
15:56:34 emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5759) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details.
15:56:34 emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5758
15:56:34 emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5758
15:56:34 emulator: trying to find console-report client on tcp:5863
15:56:34 emulator: console port number sent to remote. resuming boot
15:56:34 [android] Emulator reported that the console is available on port 5,758
15:56:34 [android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
15:56:34 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
15:56:34 emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
15:56:34 
15:56:34 emulator: Skipping metrics reporting: No user opt-in.
15:58:04 ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
15:58:04 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
15:59:47 ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
15:59:47 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
16:01:31 ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
16:01:31 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
16:03:14 ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
16:03:14 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
16:04:58 ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
16:04:58 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
16:06:42 ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
16:06:42 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
16:08:25 ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
16:08:25 [android] Timed-out after waiting 720 seconds for emulator
16:08:39 [android] Stopping Android emulator
16:08:39 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb kill-server
16:08:40 Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Any idea how to take my investigation forward?

Answer (score 1):

It was already a year ago, but here is what I suggest for everybody who tries to set up Android build process in Jenkins:

Access Jenkins machine/server directly (e.g. via ssh) and try to launch emulator from terminal. In logs posted by OP, you can see that Jenkins tried to launch emulator:

> 15:56:34 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim

Maybe 90s (90000 miliseconds) isn't enough? You can launch following command on your server from terminal:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux25.2.5/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5758 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
```

and measure how long it actually take.

If it takes too much time you may consider to keep emulator running on Jenkins machine and just assume it's always ready, so you need run following command to your UI/instrumented tests:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```